# Single: Prev and next Post in same order as main query, in all categories

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

I am using something like these arguments to order the archive loop, to order posts by a custom field.

```
$args = array(  
    'category_name' => $filter_cat, 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'year_start',
    'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' )  
);
```

On `single.php`, how can I add a link to the next post and previous post in the same order as the main query above?

I want to have the possibility to skip from one post to another through all posts (not in one category).

Answer (score 2):

So from the research I have done into this I've found out the follow:

To display the Text as a Link, without the Post Title but within the same category you would use the follow

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE ); ?>
```

To do it with the same custom taxonomy the following applies

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in taxonomy', TRUE, '', 'my_custom_taxonomy' ); ?>
```

I'm sure by looking into [`next_post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/) and [`previous_post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_post_link/) you will be able to find a way to link the links with your custom field.

Best of luck :)

Comment: thank you but how can I change the order to a custom field?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean? This will allows them to skip through from one post to another and not by category

Comment: sorry, I need to skip through one post to another in a certain order, the order is based on a custom field.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully benefit you :)